# Auto submit php form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, submit

I want to submit a form after some interval periodically. 
I have tried as follows.

```
<script language="JavaScript">  

function fncAutoSubmitForm()
{
    //alert('test alert');
    alert("B : "+document.getElementById('myform').id);     
    document.getElementById('myform').submit();     
    alert("A : "+document.getElementById('myform').id);
    setTimeout("fncAutoSubmitForm();",5000);}
```

`</script>`

displayPage.php code as follows

```
<body onload="fncAutoSubmitForm();">
```

`<form id="myform" name="myform" action="code.php" method="post">`
`some controls`
`</form>`
`</body>`

here, 
"displayPage.php" submits the page to "code.php"

 "code.php" performs required action and redirects to "displayPage.php"

It works fine when I dont use autosubmit. i.e. fncAutoSubmitForm() function

but when I use fncAutoSubmitForm() "displayPage.php" disappears

here is the actual code

```
<form action="code.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform" onload='setGenLeadId();'>
```

```
        <tr><td colspan="2"><?php if($row1['lead_call_type']=="C"){echo"<font color=red>CALLBACK Lead</font>";}?></td>
         <td  align = "right"><strong>Lead Id :</strong> </td>
        <!--<td><b><font color="red"></font>Reference Number</b></td>-->

        <td  align="left"><?php echo "" . $row1['lead_id'] ."";?></td>          
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right" ><b>Name :</b></td>
            <td  align="left"><input name="custname" id="custname" class="textbox" style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" maxlength="140" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['lead_fname'])?>"></td>                
            <td  align="right"><b>Phone :</b></td>
            <td  align="left"><input name="phone" id="phone"  style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" maxlength="10" type="text"  value = "<?php echo "" . $row1['lead_phone1'] ."";?>" ></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>                
            <td align="right"><b>City :</b></td>
            <td  align="left">
            <input name="city" id="city" class="textbox" style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" maxlength="140" type="text" value="<?php echo "" . $row1['lead_city'] ."";?>">

            </td>
            <td align="right"><b>State :</b></td>
            <td  align="left" >
            <input name="state" id="state" class="textbox" style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" maxlength="140" type="text" value="<?php echo "" . $row1['lead_state'] ."";?>">             


            </td>   
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Email-ID :</b></td>
            <td  align="left" ><input name="email" id="email" style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" class="textbox" type="text"   value = "<?php echo "" . $row1['lead_email'] ."";?>"></td> 
            <td  align="right"><b>Source </b></td>
            <td ><input type="text" name="source" id = "source"  style ="width:100%;resize: none;" maxlength="900" value="<?php echo "". $row1['lead_source'] ."";?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Address : </b></td>
            <td>
            <textarea type="text" name="address" id = "address"  style ="width:100%;resize: none;" maxlength="900" ><?php echo "". $row1['lead_address1'] ."";?></textarea> 
            </td>
            <td align="right"><b>Zip Code :</b></td>
            <td  align="left"><input name="zip" id="zip" class="textbox" style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" maxlength="140" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['lead_zip'])?>"></td>
            <!--<td  align="right"><b>Phone :</b></td>
            <td  align="left"><input name="phone" id="phone"  style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" maxlength="10" type="text"  value = "<?php //echo "" . $row1['lead_phone1'] ."";?>" ></td>-->                
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Rounds :</b></td>
            <td>
                <?php

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT param_field_value,param_field_itemdata FROM cti_service_parameters where param_service_id=$service_id and param_field_name='rounds'");
                $k=0;
                echo "<select  style='width: 100%;' id='rounds' name ='rounds'>";
                echo "<option value=".$row1['lead_rounds']." selected>".$row1['lead_rounds']."</option>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $value[$k] = $row['param_field_value'];
                    $item[$k] = $row['param_field_itemdata'];

                    if($field_val == $item[$k])

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]' selected>$value[$k]</option>";
                    else

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]'>$value[$k]</option>";

                    $k = $k + 1;
                }                   
                echo "</select>";
                ?>  
            </td>   
            <td  align="right"><b>Preparing For IIT-JEE :</b></td>
            <td  align="left">
            <?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT param_field_value,param_field_itemdata FROM cti_service_parameters where param_service_id=$service_id and param_field_name='IIT-JEE'");
                $k=0;
                echo "<select  style='width: 100%;' id='PrepIIT' name ='PrepIIT'>";
                echo "<option value=".$row1['lead_prep_iit']." selected>".$row1['lead_prep_iit']."</option>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $value[$k] = $row['param_field_value'];
                    $item[$k] = $row['param_field_itemdata'];

                    if($field_val == $item[$k])

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]' selected>$value[$k]</option>";
                    else

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]'>$value[$k]</option>";

                    $k = $k + 1;
                }

                echo "</select>";
                ?>  
            </td>               
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Which Standard :</b></td>
            <td  align="left" >
            <?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT param_field_value,param_field_itemdata FROM cti_service_parameters where param_service_id=$service_id and param_field_name='standered'");
                $k=0;
                echo "<select  style='width: 100%;' id='standared' name ='standared'>";
                echo "<option value=".$row1['lead_standared']." selected>".$row1['lead_standared']."</option>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $value[$k] = $row['param_field_value'];
                    $item[$k] = $row['param_field_itemdata'];

                    if($field_val == $item[$k])

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]' selected>$value[$k]</option>";
                    else

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]'>$value[$k]</option>";

                    $k = $k + 1;
                }

                echo "</select>";
                ?>  
            </td>   
            <td  align="right"><b>Promo DVD :</b></td>
            <td  align="left">
            <?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT param_field_value,param_field_itemdata FROM cti_service_parameters where param_service_id=$service_id and param_field_name='PromoDVD'");
                $k=0;
                echo "<select  style='width: 100%;' id='dvd' name ='dvd'>";
                echo "<option value=".$row1['lead_dvd']." selected>".$row1['lead_dvd']."</option>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $value[$k] = $row['param_field_value'];
                    $item[$k] = $row['param_field_itemdata'];

                    if($field_val == $item[$k])

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]' selected>$value[$k]</option>";
                    else

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]'>$value[$k]</option>";

                    $k = $k + 1;
                }

                echo "</select>";
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Percentage in 10th :</b></td>
            <td  align="left" ><input name="tenth" id="tenth" maxlength="5"  style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" class="textbox" type="text"   value = "<?php echo "" . $row1['lead_tenth'] ."";?>"></td>  
            <td align="right"><b>Percentage in 12th :</b></td>
            <td  align="left"  ><input name="twelth" id="twelth" maxlength="5" style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" class="textbox" type="text"  value = "<?php echo "" . $row1['lead_twelth'] ."";?>"> </td>   
            <!--<td align="right"><b>Time of Call</b></td>
            <td  align="left"  ><input name="calltime" id="calltime" style="width: 100%;height: 25%;" class="textbox" type="text"  value = "<?php// echo "" . $row1['lead_import_batch_start_date'] ."";?>" readonly>   </td>   -->
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>JEE appearing year :</b></td>
            <td  align="left" >
            <?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT param_field_value,param_field_itemdata FROM cti_service_parameters where param_service_id=$service_id and param_field_name='JeeYear'");
                $k=0;
                echo "<select  style='width: 100%;' id='jeeyear' name ='jeeyear'>";
                echo "<option value=".$row1['lead_jee_year']." selected>".$row1['lead_jee_year']."</option>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $value[$k] = $row['param_field_value'];
                    $item[$k] = $row['param_field_itemdata'];

                    if($field_val == $item[$k])

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]' selected>$value[$k]</option>";
                    else

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]'>$value[$k]</option>";

                    $k = $k + 1;
                }

                echo "</select>";
                ?>  
            </td>   
            <td  align="right"><b>Joined any classes :</b></td>
            <td  align="left">
            <?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT param_field_value,param_field_itemdata FROM cti_service_parameters where param_service_id=$service_id and param_field_name='JoinedClasses'");
                $k=0;
                echo "<select  style='width: 100%;' id='classes' name ='classes'>";
                echo "<option value=".$row1['lead_classes']." selected>".$row1['lead_classes']."</option>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $value[$k] = $row['param_field_value'];
                    $item[$k] = $row['param_field_itemdata'];

                    if($field_val == $item[$k])

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]' selected>$value[$k]</option>";
                    else

                        echo "<option value='$value[$k]'>$value[$k]</option>";

                    $k = $k + 1;
                }

                echo "</select>";
                ?>
            </td>               
        </tr>           

        <tr>
            <td  align="right"><b>Remarks :</b></td>
            <td colspan="3"><textarea type="text" name="remarks" id = "remarks"  style ="width:100%;resize: none;" maxlength="900" ><?php echo "". $row1['lead_remarks'] ."";?></textarea> </td>
        </tr>           

        <tr>
            <td colspan=4 class="tableHeading">
                <!--<b><font color="red">Note : Fields with * are Mandatory</font></b>-->
            </td>                           
        </tr>
        <!--<input type="hidden" id="clinicFlag" name="clinicFlag" value="<?php// echo $_GET["clinicFlag"]?>">-->
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td  colspan=4 style="padding:0px">
            <div align="center">
                    <input title="Save [Alt+S]" accessKey="S" class="crmbutton small save"  type="button" name="save" value="  Save  " style="width:100px;height:30px" >    
            </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

and Code.php code is as follows

```
<?php
//session_start();
//echo $_SESSION['user'];
include("connection.php");
$lead = $_POST['lead'];
$callnumber = $_POST['callnumber'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$lead_fname = $_POST['custname'];
$lead_phone1 = $_POST['phone'];     
$lead_city = $_POST['city'];
$lead_email = $_POST['email'];          
$lead_state = $_POST['state'];
$lead_address1 = $_POST['address'];
$lead_zip = $_POST['zip'];
$lead_rounds = $_POST['rounds'];
$lead_IIT = $_POST['PrepIIT'];
$lead_standared = $_POST['standared'];
$lead_dvd = $_POST['dvd'];
$lead_tenth = $_POST['tenth'];
$lead_twelth = $_POST['twelth'];
$lead_jee_year = $_POST['jeeyear'];
$lead_classes = $_POST['classes'];
$lead_remarks  = $_POST['remarks'];
$lead_source = $_POST['source'];    


if($GLOBALS['database_type'] == "MySql")
{
    $con=mysql_connect($GLOBALS['database_ip'],$GLOBALS['database_username'],$GLOBALS['database_password']);
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($GLOBALS['database_name'],$con);    

    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT service_outbound_lead_dsn_string,
                            service_outbound_lead_db_user,
                            service_outbound_lead_db_password,
                            service_leadstructure_master_tablename,
                            service_outbound_lead_db_name 
                            FROM cti_services WHERE service_id = $service");


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
        {
            $lead_dsn = $row['service_outbound_lead_dsn_string'];
            $lead_user = $row['service_outbound_lead_db_user'];
            $lead_pwd = $row['service_outbound_lead_db_password'];
            $lead_table = $row['service_leadstructure_master_tablename'];
            $lead_db = $row['service_outbound_lead_db_name'];
        }

    if($_POST['save'])
    {   
    //input_app_datetime = '$lead_appointment', 
    //input_app_reschedule = '$lead_reschedule',


    mysql_select_db($GLOBALS['database_name'],$con);    


    $sqlquery = ("UPDATE $lead_db.$lead_table set lead_fname = '$lead_fname', lead_phone1 = '$lead_phone1', lead_email = '$lead_email', lead_remarks = '$lead_remarks', lead_address1 = '$lead_address1', lead_state = '$lead_state', lead_city = '$lead_city', lead_zip = '$lead_zip', lead_rounds ='$lead_rounds', lead_prep_iit ='$lead_IIT', lead_standared ='$lead_standared', lead_dvd ='$lead_dvd', lead_tenth ='$lead_tenth', lead_twelth ='$lead_twelth', lead_jee_year ='$lead_jee_year', lead_classes ='$lead_classes', lead_source ='$lead_source' WHERE lead_id=$lead");



        $dbSql = mysql_query($sqlquery) or die("Error : " . mysql_error()); 
        $sql="update cti_call_master set crm_remarks='$lead_remarks' where call_number=$callnumber";
        $dbSql1 = mysql_query($sql);
        //$flag = "saved";
        $message = "Lead Id-".$lead." Data Saved .....";
        //$message = $sqlquery;
        //header("location:vision.php?LEADID=$lead&SERVICEID=$service&CALLNUMBER=$callnumber&MESSAGE=$message&FLAG=$flag&CLI=$lead_phone1&clinicFlag=$clinicFlag&alterno=$alter_no");                       
        header("location:displayPage.php?LEADID=$lead&SERVICEID=$service&CALLNUMBER=$callnumber&MESSAGE=$message&FLAG=$flag&CLI=$lead_phone1");
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: what do you mean by '"displayPage.php" disappears' ?

Comment: when i try to submit form onload of <body>, the "displayPage.php" is not displayed when "fncAutoSubmitForm()" is called

Comment: Are you trying to keep submitting the form every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the following function at 'onload' event. It will submit the form after 5 second to your code.php

```
function fncAutoSubmitForm() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Then your code.php will process the form action and redirect it back to displayPage.php.

Can you check if your form is not submitted at all to code.php or it is being submitted to code.php and due to some error it fails to redirect back to displayPage.php. In the later case you can turn ON the display error settings if it is not already ON. Use following in code.php to enable:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

It it doesn't help then pls provide the code to get the actual scenario here.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ajax call method to accomplish the same as suggested in previous answer.

Comment: thanks @user3438533,
there was this error "Notice: Undefined index: save in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vision\code.php on line 94"

but code.php is present in the directory. And when i submit page on click of button it works

Comment: It is a notice type error only..But I guess its explaining the reason behind the redirection problem..this is because it is not able to identify the value for $_POST['save'] and hence not going to your if($_POST['save']) condition and resulting in displaying a blank page rather redirection to displayPage.php

Answer (score 1):

As you call *fncAutoSubmitForm()* onload of displayPage.php, it immediately triggers *document.getElementById('myform').submit();*

So you are redirected to code.php, the action of your form.

If you want a delay you should not apply *fncAutoSubmitForm()* onload of the page.

but more something like:

```
setTimeout("fncAutoSubmitForm();",5000);}

function fncAutoSubmitForm(){
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}
```

But you won't stay on *displayPage.php* it will redirect you to *code.php*. If you want to always display the same page you needs to change the action target in your form.

Comment: @user3713775 as martingo89 suggested you can try to use ajax, the page won't reload every 5 sec

Comment: I tried this but still page is not coming after sumbit. And I want to redirect it to "code.php" only that page will inturn redirects to "displayPage.php" again

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        submit();
    }, 1000);
});

function submit(){
    var data;
    // extract data from your form and save it to data variable
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: data
    });
}
```